# Performing batch join in pyspark from timestamp and id using watermarking

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes with on equipment and equipment surrounding information. A row from the on equipment dataframe has the following schema:

```py
on_equipment_df.head()

# Output of notebook:
Row(
on_eq_equipid='1', 
on_eq_timestamp=datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 7, 15, 27, 42, 866098), 
on_eq_charge=3.917107463423725, on_eq_electric_consumption=102.02754516792204, on_eq_force=10.551710736897613, on_eq_humidity=22.663245200558457, on_eq_pressure=10.813417893943944, on_eq_temperature=29.80448721128125, on_eq_vibration=4.376662536641158, 
measurement_status='Bad')
```

And a row from the equipment surrounding looks like:

```py
equipment_surrounding_df.head()

# Output of notebook
Row(
eq_surrounding_equipid='1', 
eq_surrounding_timestamp=datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 7, 15, 27, 42, 903198),
eq_surrounding_dust=24.0885168316774, eq_surrounding_humidity=16.949569353381793, eq_surrounding_noise=12.256649392702574, eq_surrounding_temperature=8.141877435145844,
measurement_status='Good')
```

Notice that both tables have id's identifying the equipment and a timestamp relating to when the measurement was taken.

Problem: I want to perform a join between these two dataframes based on equipment id and the timestamps. The issue is that the timestamp is recorded with a very precise reading rendering the join through timestamp impossible (unless I round the timestamp, which I would like to leave as a last resort). The on equipment and equipment surrounding readings are recorded at different frequencies. I want therefore to perform a join only based on the equipment id but for windows between certain timestamp values. This is similar to what is done in structured streaming using watermarking.

To do this I tried to use the equivelent operation used in structured streaming as mentioned above called watermarking. Here is the code:

```py
# Add watermark defined by the timestamp column of each df
watermarked_equipment_surr = equipment_surrounding_df.withWatermark("eq_surr_timestamp", "0.2 seconds")
watermarked_on_equipment = on_equipment_df.withWatermark("on_eq_timestamp", "0.2 seconds")

# Define new equipment dataframe based on the watermarking conditions described
equipment_df = watermarked_on_equipment.join(
    watermarked_equipment_surr, 
    expr("""
        on_eq_equipid = eq_surr_equipid AND
        on_eq_timestamp >= eq_surrounding_timestamp AND
        on_eq_timestamp <= eq_surrounding_timestamp + interval 0.2 seconds
        """))

# Perfrom a count (error appears here)
print("Equipment size:", equipment_df.count())
```

I get an error when performing this action. Based on this, I have two questions:

1. Is this the right way to solve such a use case / problem?
2. If so, why do I get an error in my code?

Thank you in advance

**UPDATE:**

So I beleive I found half the solution inspiered by:

[Joining two spark dataframes on time (TimestampType) in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30630296/joining-two-spark-dataframes-on-time-timestamptype-in-python)

Essentially the solution goes through creating two columns in one of the dataframes which represents an upper and lower limit of the timestamp using udfs. The code for that:

```py
def lower_range_func(x, offset_milli=250):
    """
    From a timestamp and offset, get the timestamp obtained from subtractng the offset.
    """
    return x - timedelta(seconds=offset_milli/1000)

def upper_range_func(x,  offset_milli=250):
    """
    From a timestamp and offset, get the timestamp obtained from adding the offset.
    """
    return x + timedelta(seconds=offset_milli/1000)

# Create two dataframes
lower_range = udf(lower_range_func, TimestampType())
upper_range = udf(upper_range_func, TimestampType())

# Add these columns to the on_equipment dataframe
on_equipment_df = on_equipment_df\
    .withColumn('lower_on_eq_timestamp', lower_range(on_equipment_df["on_eq_timestamp"]))\
    .withColumn('upper_on_eq_timestamp', upper_range(on_equipment_df["on_eq_timestamp"]))
```

Once we have those columns, we can perform a filtered join using these new columns.

```
# Join dataframes based on a filtered join
equipment_df = on_equipment_df.join(equipment_surrounding_df)\
    .filter(on_equipment_df.on_eq_timestamp > equipment_surrounding_df.lower_eq_surr_timestamp)\
    .filter(on_equipment_df.on_eq_timestamp < equipment_surrounding_df.upper_eq_surr_timestamp)
```

The problem is, as soon as I try to join using also the equipment id, like so:

```
# Join dataframes based on a filtered join
equipment_df = on_equipment_df.join(
equipment_surrounding_df, on_equipment_df.on_eq_equipid == equipment_surrounding_df.eq_surr_equipid)\
    .filter(on_equipment_df.on_eq_timestamp > equipment_surrounding_df.lower_eq_surr_timestamp)\
    .filter(on_equipment_df.on_eq_timestamp < equipment_surrounding_df.upper_eq_surr_timestamp)
```

I get the an error. Any thoughts on this approach?