# How to perform conditional join with time column in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am looking for help in joining 2 DF's with conditional join in time columns, using Spark Scala.

#### DF1

| time_1 | revision | review_1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-05 08:32:00 | 1 | abc |
| 2022-04-05 10:15:00 | 2 | abc |
| 2022-04-05 12:15:00 | 3 | abc |
| 2022-04-05 09:00:00 | 1 | xyz |
| 2022-04-05 20:20:00 | 2 | xyz |

#### DF2:

| time_2 | review_1 | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-05 08:30:00 | abc | value_1 |
| 2022-04-05 09:48:00 | abc | value_2 |
| 2022-04-05 15:40:00 | abc | value_3 |
| 2022-04-05 08:00:00 | xyz | value_4 |
| 2022-04-05 09:00:00 | xyz | value_5 |
| 2022-04-05 10:00:00 | xyz | value_6 |
| 2022-04-05 11:00:00 | xyz | value_7 |
| 2022-04-05 12:00:00 | xyz | value_8 |

#### Desired Output DF:

| time_1 | revision | review_1 | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-05 08:32:00 | 1 | abc | value_1 |
| 2022-04-05 10:15:00 | 2 | abc | value_2 |
| 2022-04-05 12:15:00 | 3 | abc | null |
| 2022-04-05 09:00:00 | 1 | xyz | value_6 |
| 2022-04-05 20:20:00 | 2 | xyz | null |

*As in the case of row 4 of the final output (where `time_1` = `2022-04-05 09:00:00`, if multiple values match during the join then only the latest - in time - should be taken).*

*Furthermore if there is no match for a row of `df` in the join then there it should have `null` for the `value` column.*

Here we need to join between 2 columns in the two DF's:

- `review_1 === review_2` &&
- `time_1 === time_2` (condition : time_1 should be in range +1/-1 Hr from time_2, If multiple records then show latest value, as in value_6 above)

Comment: I would recommend editing your question to format your dataframe's to make them more readable. Though a python example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30719662/2743131) is quite relevant and my have the full solution you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code necessary to join the DataFrames:

*I have commented the code so as to explain the logic.*

## TL;DR

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val SECONDS_IN_ONE_HOUR = 60 * 60

val window = Window.partitionBy("time_1").orderBy(col("time_2").desc)

df1WithEpoch
    .join(df2WithEpoch, 
          df1WithEpoch("review_1") === df2WithEpoch("review_2") 
          && (
              // if `time_1` is in between `time_2` and `time_2` - 1 hour
              (df1WithEpoch("epoch_time_1") >= df2WithEpoch("epoch_time_2") - SECONDS_IN_ONE_HOUR)
              // if `time_1` is in between `time_2` and `time_2` + 1 hour
              && (df1WithEpoch("epoch_time_1") <= df2WithEpoch("epoch_time_2") + SECONDS_IN_ONE_HOUR)
          ),
          // LEFT OUTER is necessary to get back `2022-04-05 12:15:00` and `2022-04-05 20:20:00` which have no join to `df2` in the time window
          "left_outer"
         )
    .withColumn("row_num", row_number().over(window))
    .filter(col("row_num") === 1)
    // select only the columns we care about
    .select("time_1", "revision", "review_1", "value")
    // order by to give the results in the same order as in the Question
    .orderBy(col("review_1"), col("revision"))
    .show(false)
```

---

## Full breakdown

Let's start off with your DataFrames: `df1` and `df2` in code:

```scala
val df1 = List(
    ("2022-04-05 08:32:00", 1, "abc"),
    ("2022-04-05 10:15:00", 2, "abc"),
    ("2022-04-05 12:15:00", 3, "abc"),
    ("2022-04-05 09:00:00", 1, "xyz"),
    ("2022-04-05 20:20:00", 2, "xyz")
).toDF("time_1", "revision", "review_1")

df1.show(false)
```

gives:

```
+-------------------+--------+--------+
|time_1             |revision|review_1|
+-------------------+--------+--------+
|2022-04-05 08:32:00|1       |abc     |
|2022-04-05 10:15:00|2       |abc     |
|2022-04-05 12:15:00|3       |abc     |
|2022-04-05 09:00:00|1       |xyz     |
|2022-04-05 20:20:00|2       |xyz     |
+-------------------+--------+--------+
```

```scala
val df2 = List(
    ("2022-04-05 08:30:00", "abc", "value_1"),
    ("2022-04-05 09:48:00", "abc", "value_2"),
    ("2022-04-05 15:40:00", "abc", "value_3"),
    ("2022-04-05 08:00:00", "xyz", "value_4"),
    ("2022-04-05 09:00:00", "xyz", "value_5"),
    ("2022-04-05 10:00:00", "xyz", "value_6"),
    ("2022-04-05 11:00:00", "xyz", "value_7"),
    ("2022-04-05 12:00:00", "xyz", "value_8")
).toDF("time_2", "review_2", "value")

df2.show(false)
```

gives:

```
+-------------------+--------+-------+
|time_2             |review_2|value  |
+-------------------+--------+-------+
|2022-04-05 08:30:00|abc     |value_1|
|2022-04-05 09:48:00|abc     |value_2|
|2022-04-05 15:40:00|abc     |value_3|
|2022-04-05 08:00:00|xyz     |value_4|
|2022-04-05 09:00:00|xyz     |value_5|
|2022-04-05 10:00:00|xyz     |value_6|
|2022-04-05 11:00:00|xyz     |value_7|
|2022-04-05 12:00:00|xyz     |value_8|
+-------------------+--------+-------+
```

Next we need new columns which we can do the date range check on (where time is represented as a single number, making math operations easy:

```scala
// add a new column, temporarily, which contains the time in 
// epoch format: with this adding/subtracting an hour can easily be done.
val df1WithEpoch = df1.withColumn("epoch_time_1", unix_timestamp(col("time_1")))
val df2WithEpoch = df2.withColumn("epoch_time_2", unix_timestamp(col("time_2")))

df1WithEpoch.show()
df2WithEpoch.show()
```

gives:

```
+-------------------+--------+--------+------------+
|             time_1|revision|review_1|epoch_time_1|
+-------------------+--------+--------+------------+
|2022-04-05 08:32:00|       1|     abc|  1649147520|
|2022-04-05 10:15:00|       2|     abc|  1649153700|
|2022-04-05 12:15:00|       3|     abc|  1649160900|
|2022-04-05 09:00:00|       1|     xyz|  1649149200|
|2022-04-05 20:20:00|       2|     xyz|  1649190000|
+-------------------+--------+--------+------------+

+-------------------+--------+-------+------------+
|             time_2|review_2|  value|epoch_time_2|
+-------------------+--------+-------+------------+
|2022-04-05 08:30:00|     abc|value_1|  1649147400|
|2022-04-05 09:48:00|     abc|value_2|  1649152080|
|2022-04-05 15:40:00|     abc|value_3|  1649173200|
|2022-04-05 08:00:00|     xyz|value_4|  1649145600|
|2022-04-05 09:00:00|     xyz|value_5|  1649149200|
|2022-04-05 10:00:00|     xyz|value_6|  1649152800|
|2022-04-05 11:00:00|     xyz|value_7|  1649156400|
|2022-04-05 12:00:00|     xyz|value_8|  1649160000|
+-------------------+--------+-------+------------+
```

and finally to `join`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val SECONDS_IN_ONE_HOUR = 60 * 60

val window = Window.partitionBy("time_1").orderBy(col("time_2").desc)

df1WithEpoch
    .join(df2WithEpoch, 
          df1WithEpoch("review_1") === df2WithEpoch("review_2") 
          && (
              // if `time_1` is in between `time_2` and `time_2` - 1 hour
              (df1WithEpoch("epoch_time_1") >= df2WithEpoch("epoch_time_2") - SECONDS_IN_ONE_HOUR)
              // if `time_1` is in between `time_2` and `time_2` + 1 hour
              && (df1WithEpoch("epoch_time_1") <= df2WithEpoch("epoch_time_2") + SECONDS_IN_ONE_HOUR)
          ),
          // LEFT OUTER is necessary to get back `2022-04-05 12:15:00` and `2022-04-05 20:20:00` which have no join to `df2` in the time window
          "left_outer"
         )
    .withColumn("row_num", row_number().over(window))
    .filter(col("row_num") === 1)
    // select only the columns we care about
    .select("time_1", "revision", "review_1", "value")
    // order by to give the results in the same order as in the Question
    .orderBy(col("review_1"), col("revision"))
    .show(false)
```

gives:

```
+-------------------+--------+--------+-------+
|time_1             |revision|review_1|value  |
+-------------------+--------+--------+-------+
|2022-04-05 08:32:00|1       |abc     |value_1|
|2022-04-05 10:15:00|2       |abc     |value_2|
|2022-04-05 12:15:00|3       |abc     |null   |
|2022-04-05 09:00:00|1       |xyz     |value_6|
|2022-04-05 20:20:00|2       |xyz     |null   |
+-------------------+--------+--------+-------+
```